# How to lock or protect row after data entry or input in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, locking, row, data-entry

How to lock or protect a row after data entry or input in Google sheet. Column F is a "Timestamp" and it is a blank all time. I need to protect the Row when F not a blank.

Answer (score 1):

**Protecting a row in which column F is not Blank**

```
function onEdit() {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='TheNameOfTheSheetYouWantThisToWorkIn')return;//change to whatever sheet your using
  if(e.range.columnStart==6 && !e.range.isBlank()) {
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).protect();
  }
}
```

[Read about simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

[Learn more about onEdit event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Requested Integration:

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Activity Log' && e.range.columnStart==2 && e.range.rowStart>1) {
     applyFirstLevelValidation(e.value,e.range.rowStart);
  }
  if(sh.getName()=='Activity Log' && e.range.columnStart==3 && e.range.rowStart>1) {
    applySecondLevelValidation(e.value,e.range.rowStart);
  }
  if(sh.getName()=="SheetName" && e.range.columnStart==6 && !e.range.isBlank()) { //you need to modify the SheetName
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).protect(); 
  } 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)
but i have many onEdit function  in my cod and this make a conflict

Comment: I can believe that.  Many people over use this function greatly, often creating very complex situations.  I hardly ever use them.  I just run a function and wait a moment.  It puts a lot less stress of the server too and it gets the job done.

Comment: i think it's my mistake please help me and check my cod and feedback me :)
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wcUUU0GdotuCny1jJ_aGuQU4H4vtMlC8ixYSMOkuMGA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That is not a public link.

Comment: sorry for delay 

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wcUUU0GdotuCny1jJ_aGuQU4H4vtMlC8ixYSMOkuMGA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: While I would suggest that you combine all of your onEdit functions into one and figure out how to integrate them together.  Because when they get a trigger they get it all at the same time.  So it would probably be better for you to control how they respond.

Comment: can you do this for me ?

Comment: Check the answer.  Hopefully all of that get's done in less than 30 seconds otherwise your script will time out.

Comment: i don't know what happened all users in sheet can edit now :)

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks for your reply :) but i have many onEdit function in my cod and this make a conflict please check the below **

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wcUUU0GdotuCny1jJ_aGuQU4H4vtMlC8ixYSMOkuMGA/edit?usp=sharing